# SIPp - Multiple client SIP Invite to single server -

Tags: linux, sip, uac

I am trying to find a way to send a large amount of SIP INVITE from my linux OS to a remote application that accept SIP INVITE.

I found a way to send many SIP INVITE from the same source (i.e. **ip.ethernetcard local linux os**):

sipp -sn uac **ip.remote.app** -i **ip.ethernetcard local linux os** -m 10 -s "name.user"

This send 10 SIP INVITE. The problem is when I look at the log on the remote side (using tcpdump), I see that source is always the same (**ip.ethernetcard local linux os**). Is there a way to minimic different sources i.e. we are pretending that we have multiple clients talking to the remote app ?

Comment: And how is this a programming question? Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Read more about the injection files and you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Injecting values from an external CSV during calls
You can use "-inf file_name" as a command line parameter to input values into the scenarios. The first line of the file should say whether the data is to be read in sequence (SEQUENTIAL), random order (RANDOM), or in a user based manner (USER). Each line corresponds to one call and has one or more ';' delimited data fields and they can be referred as [field0], [field1], ... in the xml scenario file. Example:

SEQUENTIAL

sipp1
sipp2
sipp3
...

Will be read in sequence (first call will use first line, second call second line). At any place where the keyword "[field0]" appears in the scenario file, it will be replaced by either "sipp1", "sipp2" or "sipp3" depending on the call.

As before, use

sipp  -sn uac **ip.remote.app** -i **ip.ethernetcard_local_linux_os** -m 10 -s "name.user"

add -inf file_name and -sf uac.xml

In the xml file (standard example taken from sipp web page), replace

sip:**sipp**[local_ip]:[local_port]>;tag=[call_number]

sip:**[field0]**@[local_ip]:[local_port]>;tag=[call_number]

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Use some sip stress test tool such as [SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/) to generate varied INVITE messages.